# How do we solve the equation $4^{x} + 2^{x} = 20$?

Tags: logarithms

It is easy that $x = 2$ below, but can I solve it with a general formula?

$$4^x + 2^x = 20$$

Comment: Try the substitution $y = 2^{x}$.

Comment: Hint: $4^x = (2^x)^2$

Comment: For this particular question, you can note that if $x < y$, then $2^x + 4^x < 2^y + 4^y$ and hence, the equation can have at most one root. You have already found one by inspection.

Comment: but if the equation is more difficult to solve by inspections. Lets say, 0.94^x + 0.5^x = 1. Now I cant factorize any term to make same base. (if that was the hint :))

Answer (score 2):

Do the substitution $t=2^x$, then solve the quadratic equation you get. Undo the subsitution, you will have to decide whether one answer works or not.